# Blender assign material to object -> Unity

Tags: unity

I haven't found a tutorial about it and I'm completely lost. I've applied materials for assets I've made, never touched the Texture properties however, but the materials wont ever follow. I've read things on the internet where people say that it's just about drag and drop the textures. But I haven't found any that I used in Blender...

It's really annoying when you've spent hours on making something, and then not seeing it as it's done in the game is annoying.

Am I just stupid, or can you find a solution to it? Because I would be more than thankful for it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use image textures? If so you simply drag the image files into unity. You can't import procedural textures or materials created using cycles nodes.

Comment: I use the "Add a new material slot", add the color I want and then I apply that to whatever. I don't use image textures since I'm doing a low poly art project.

Comment: check out the quick tutorial video on youtube "FBX Importing to Unity 2017/2018+ | Where did my textures go?" it wraps up the issue how to assign your textures to your material.